# Sort string values delimited by commas in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, delimited

I have this dataframe, and I'm looking a pythonic way using Pandas to sort these values.
Column 2 is a string.

```
C1   C2
0    b,g,f
1    a,f,c
2    f,e,a,c
```

The Output should look like:

```
C1   C2
0    b,f,g
1    a,c,f
2    a,c,e,f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        "C1":0,
        "C2":"b,g,f"
    },
    {
        "C1":1,
        "C2":"c,b,a"
    },
    {
        "C1":2,
        "C2":"f,e,a,c"
    }
]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df.C2 = df.C2.sort_values().apply(lambda x: ",".join(sorted(x.split(","))))
print(df)
```