# Is there a way to sort number within number

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Excel file:

```
5432
321
9870

import pandas as pd


file = 'read.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(file)
print(df1)
```

I want to sort the number within the number into

```
2345
1234
0789
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70075110/sort-string-values-delimited-by-commas-in-a-column-using-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with convert values to `string`s with `sorted`:

```
#read excel file without header, so column is 0
df1 = pd.read_excel(file, header=None)

df1['new'] = [''.join(sorted(str(x))) for x in df1[0]]
print (df1)
    col
0  2345
1  1234
2  0789
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I got error when copy over

Comment: import pandas as pd

file = 'read.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file)

df['col'] = [''.join(sorted(str(x))) for x in df['col']]
print(df)

Comment: import pandas as pd


file = 'read.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(file)

print(df.columns)   my output is :Int64Index([4321], dtype='int64')

Comment: my excel file is just 5432
3210
9870

Comment: @jjbkd - Understand, answer is edited.

Comment: df['4321'] = [''.join(sorted(str(x))) for x in df['4321']] , indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key) ,     raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: '4321' i still get error after changed to 4321

Comment: @jjbkd - add `header=None` to `read_excel` and then `df[0]` instead `df['4321']`

Comment: okok got it many thks i will try to understand your code thks again

Comment: ''.join(sorted(str(x)))  "'.join what does this mean"? str(x) is convert to string right?

Comment: @jjbkd - it is called list comprehension - looping by each value of column `df[1]`, convert to string, sorted and join values back to string.

Comment: do you have any link for me to read up list comprehension to understand sorry i still new in python still trying to learn thks

Comment: @jjbkd - e.g. check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)